# Drupal 7 log-in form doesn't react

Tags: users

Out of the blue I'm unable to login into my website:
http://karlssonwilker.com/dev_v2/kw/user

I type my username and my password and upon clicking "log-in" or pressing RETURN nothing happens. 
Could it be something related with the database? Disabling javascript, css, removing any custom functions, or clearing the cache tables on phpmydamin seems to have no affect.

No idea what the problem is.

I had a test user created before I started having this problem. You can use it if you care to try.
user: test
pass: test

Anyone came across a similar problem?

Thanks!

Comment: If it's Drupal 6 make sure you have the anonymous user (uid:0) record in the users table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've noticed that your Drupal installation is at http://karlssonwilker.com/dev_v2/kw/ which is a subdirectory. This can mess up some rewrite rules in .htaccess when using clean urls.

Go to .htaccess and find this line that is greyed out.

```
# RewriteBase /drupal
```

You should uncomment that and replace it with...

```
RewriteBase /dev_v2/kw
```

This will most likely fix your problem. If you are using some sort of CVS and this is a staging site, I would recommend ignoring the .htaccess file. I wouldn't want you to accidentally destroying your live site.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your HTML:

```
<div id="node_container" <form="" action="/dev_v2/kw/user" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8"><div><div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-name">
```

This is definitely not interpreted as form.

Comment: Hi Potney, 
Thank you for answer.
I've changed the HTML and the form is now responding.  But still no success logging in

Comment: Are you sure these are the correct credentials? Run a one time login (drush uli) change the password and check again.

Comment: Reseting the password or inputing the correct password redirects you to the user log-in form and keeps you logged out.